# How to put an Api key in the Authenticate message?

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to combine the api key auth provider with the encrypted messaging plugin.

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(home);
client.BearerToken = "somesecret";
```

works

but i want my apikey to be in the message so i tried

```
        var authResponse = client.Post(new Authenticate
        {
            provider = ApiKeyAuthProvider.Name, 
            UserName = "somesecret"                                         
        });
```

This post fails at runtime with a 401 not authenticated.

How do i get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IAuthWithRequest` Auth Providers like the [API Key Auth Provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider) needs to be **sent per request** with the Authenticated User Session it establishes only lasts for the **lifetime of that request**. It can't be used with the `Authenticate` Service to Authenticate the client as your example tried to do, it must be included in each request to an Authenticated Service.

The normal way to call a protected Service with the API Key is to just populate the `BearerToken` property:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl) {
    BearerToken = apiKey
};
```

Which will then let you call your `[Authenticate]` Service:

```
var response = client.Get(new Secure { Name = "World" });
```

#### Encrypted Messaging Support

Previously you could only embed the [User SessionId](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) within an Encrypted Messaging Request but I've just added support for [Authenticating Encrypted Messaging Services](http://docs.servicestack.net/encrypted-messaging#authentication-with-encrypted-messaging)  with a BearerToken in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/4d5592cb8a8964ab242d67dea00413953595e862) which works similar to populating a `SessionId`, where you can now populate a `BearerToken` as used in [API Key](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider) and [JWT Auth Providers](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) by having your Request DTOs implement `IHasBearerToken`, e.g:

```
public class Secure : IHasBearerToken
{
    public string BearerToken { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This will let you embed the `BearerToken` when calling the protected Service, e.g:

```
IEncryptedClient encryptedClient = client.GetEncryptedClient(publicKey);
var response = encryptedClient.Get(new Secure { BearerToken = apiKey, Name = "World" });
```

Where it will be embedded and encrypted along with all content in the Request DTO.

Alternatively you can also set the `BearerToken` property on the `IEncryptedClient` once and it will automatically populate it on all Request DTOs that implement `IHasBearerToken`, e.g:

```
encryptedClient.BearerToken = apiKey;
var response = encryptedClient.Get(new Secure { Name = "World" });
```

The new BearerToken support in Encrypted Messaging is available from v5.1.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).